# unregister app in App check from SafetyNet in firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, safetynet, firebase-app-check

I have registered App in safetyNet in App check in firebase console but, now I have to unregistered
the app in safetyNet or disable safetyNet, How I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a little tricky and not intuitive since you have cannot remove the fingerprint on the App Check tab in your products settings.

Instead, you must go to **"Project settings > General > Your apps"** at the bottom of the frame there is a "SHA certificate fingerprints" section which should contain the fingerprint you used to register your app in safetyNet. Hovering over this fingerprint will display a trash icon which you can use to delete the fingerprint.

Navigating back to the App Check tab will show that the app in question is no longer registered with safetyNet

Comment: What if I want to remove SafetyNet completely? Because when I add SHA-256 again it activates safetyNet again !

Comment: Have the same issue, any updates on a real solution?

Comment: have the same issue :(

Comment: Any updates on this yet?